# Split strings keeping all trailing empty elements

Tags: java, regex

I am relatively new to java programming. How would you split following lines of Strings separated by semicolons?

```
String; String; String; String, String; String;;String;
String; String; String; ;String;String;String;String
```

I would like to pass each String as an argument into a constructor (from txt file), but I am unable to find passable regex for the purpose. The constructor has 8 String arguments (from where there is nothing between two semicolons `;;`, I would like to get an empty String). In this case two separate objects would be created. I am aware of how splitting a String generally works but this one seems to be too tricky for me.

Comment: Use the split method of String with the semicolon as separator

Comment: Why does it seem tricky? What are you trying to achieve and where are you stuck? Also, you have a comma in the first line (`String, String`)

Comment: Well. I tried (";"), ("\\W") and (\\;) regular expressions but I always get java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: @stribizhev Pls read the question again "The constructor has 8 String arguments (from where there is nothing between two semicolons ;;, I would like to get an empty String)" Your code doesn't return the last argument in the first case the OP has provided, `tokens.length == 7` for that case

Comment: @ferrybig: That is not mine, that is Anordil's answer. Yes, the last empty element is omitted. I posted my answer where I am describing how to avoid omitting trailing empty elements.

Comment: @Laarup: Please consider reviewing the current answers and accepting the one that works for you best, upvoting all answers that turned out useful to you.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is the [`String.Split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) does not keep the trailing empty elements:

> Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.

To include them, use `-1` as the second argument (see [demo](https://ideone.com/g5pwq8)):

```
String s  = "String; String; String; String, String; String;;String;";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.split(";", -1)));
```

See this [Java reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29):

> **`public String[] split(String regex, int limit)`**
>   The *limit* parameter controls the number of times the pattern is applied and therefore affects the length of the resulting array... ***If `n` is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible and the array can have any length***. If `n` is zero then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible, the array can have any length, and *trailing empty strings will be discarded*.

Answer (score 3):

Your answer is in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).

```
String toto = "A;B;C;D";

String[] tokens = toto.split(";");
```

Comment: There are double `;` and a random `,`. This is not going to work.

Comment: Using split without any argument is the same as calling it with a limit of '0' tokens, which, according to the Javadoc, will indeed return empty matches.

Comment: There is still the random `,`.

Comment: Which isn't a separator according to what the OP said, so it may very well be valid for an argument to contain a comma.

Comment: Yes, that argument contains a comma.

Answer (score 1):

Since you stated that you want to contain the spaces, only split on the `;` and want to keep 8 arguments for your constructor, we are going to use the split with a limit method.

[String.split(String,int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int))

**Example:**

```
String in = "String; String; String; String, String; String;;String;";
String[] s1 = in.split(";");
```

Gives:

```
["String"," String"," String, String"," String"," String","","String"]
```

What is **only** 7 in length and will **fail** your constructor.

---

```
String[] s = in.split(";",8);
```

Gives:

```
["String"," String"," String"," String, String"," String","","String",""]`
```

What is 8 in length and will work.

---

You can then address your constructor using:

```
YourObject obj = new YourObject(s[0],s[1],s[2],s[3],s[4],s[5],s[6],s[7]);
```