# Issue with splitting Java String by regex

Tags: java, regex

guys! I've got a URL in which I want to encode every character but slashes "/". I've tried to use String.split() function, but it doesn't work as I'd like it to:

```
String url1 = "/images";
String url2 = "/images/";

url1.split("/"); // gives me {"", "images"}
url2.split("/"); // gives me the same array {"", "images"}, when I expect {"", "images", ""}
```

How can I get {"", "images", ""} array for string like "/images/" ? Maybe I need to use another regex?

Comment: use `split("/",-1)` to get trailing empty strings. but you should rather use the build ins for URL´s if you are trying to parse them.

Comment: See explanation [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34041861/3832970).